# Conditional Statement Printing Error

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am attempting to write a script to include an input from the user that represents a "Minimum Confidence Threshold". I want to use this value to only save & print records to the feature class that have a confidence level above (greater than) this threshold.
The data is from a .txt file.

My current code is still printing all 411 records. If I have a confidence level of 99 for example, it should only print out 23 record. I think there must be an error with the way I have arranged my statements or indentations.Any advice?

```
import arcpy

work = raw_input("Enter the full path of WildlandFires.mdb: ") # C:\Scripts\Lab 7 Data\WildlandFires.mdb
arcpy.env.workspace = work # Set the workspace to the geodatabase
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

iFile = raw_input("Enter the full path of wildfire text file: ")# input text file C:\Scripts\Lab 7 Data\NorthAmericaWildfires_2007275.txt 

output = raw_input("Enter the name of the output feature class: ")
threshold = raw_input("Specify the minimum confidence threshold: ")

f = open(iFile, 'r')# input text file C:\Scripts\Lab 7 Data\NorthAmericaWildfires_2007275.txt in "read" mode

lstFires = f.readlines() # Read the lines of fire data from the input file
f.close() # close the file 

field = ["SHAPE@", "CONFIVALUE"] # represents the field names for each row in the feature class

# Process: Create Feature Class
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(work, output, "POINT")

arcpy.AddField_management(output, "CONFIVALUE", "FLOAT")

cursor_new = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output, field)# add the new points that you will create to the "NewFires" feature class

cntr = 0 # counter variable

for fire in lstFires:
        if 'Latitude' in fire: # Skip the header
                continue
        pnt2 = arcpy.Point() # Create a new Point object
        lstValues = fire.split(',') # create a list of values "lstValues" based on the type of delimiter
        str_int = lstValues [-3:]       
        str_int = list(map(float, str_int)) #turns string to integers
        latitude = str_int[0] # Latitude
        longitude = str_int[1] # Longitude
        confid = str_int[2] # Confidence Value 

        if (confid > threshold):
                pnt2.X = longitude # Assign the X and Y properties of the Point object
                pnt2.Y = latitude        

        row = [pnt2, confid] # Create a new row for the feature class
        cursor_new.insertRow(row) # Insert the new row to the feature class                
        cntr = cntr + 1 # update the counter
        print "Record # " + str(cntr) + " written to feature class"

del cursor_new # release the cursor lock on the feature class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indent the four lines starting from row=... The issue in your code is, you want to create a point if the confidence value from the text file is above the threshold but with this current indentation, you are creating a point for all lines, but only the ones above the threshold appears, the rest has no geometry/

Comment: adding those remaining lines to the second 'if' loop returns nothing. I wanted it to print out the records that did have a threshold > confid

Comment: Then make sure both confid and threshold variables are numeric.

Comment: That worked I used    threshold = eval(raw_input("Specify the minimum confidence threshold: ")) to make sure it was reading an integer and not a string.